# Kafka CLI tools location in wurstmeister/kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have kafka to has deployed in docker container.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
```

I saw in one of the videos that kafka toolkit is present in distributions along the path

**/usr/bin**

The kafka toolkit is not in this image at that location

maybe this set can be installed somehow , or is it present in any other kafka images ?

Comment: The "toolkit" must be installed to actually run the broker. Unclear what video you're referring to

Comment: It was in one of those video lessons that talks about kafka

Comment: It'd be great if you could link to it because it sounds like what you watched was not using that container

Comment: Unfortunately, this video is closed. but there really seemed to be another image based on which the kafka container was deployed

Comment: There are at least 4 popular Kafka Docker images I'm aware of. It's possible they used a different one (or wrote their own). But still, the Kafka shell scripts should be on the PATH of the container, so you shouldnt care about the folder location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the github repo that is used to create the wurstmeister/kafka docker image.
You can see in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) that the KAFKA_HOME points to /opt/kafka
so you will find you bin directory under /opt/kafka/bin.